# S3 put_object() not putting base folder when putting a file with prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am seeing some weird behaviour and want to understand if I am doing something wrong or not.

I have an empty bucket: `test-bucket`
Running the code below:

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('test-bucket').put_object(Key='sub/file.txt')
```

The new structure of the bucket looks like this:

```
test-bucket
└───sub
    └───file.txt
```

Now if I run `s3.Bucket('test-bucket').objects.all()` it returns `['sub/file.txt']` only.

However, if I manually create this folder `sub` first on s3 and then run `s3.Bucket('test-bucket').put_object(Key='sub/file.txt')` it returns `['sub/', 'sub/file.txt']`

Can someone help me figure out why.
Thank you

Comment: If you want that output you need to iterate the actual result of the call, split at all `/` and figure out the folders yourself.

Comment: @luk2302 if that folder was created first manually, I do receive it in the output of objects.all() Why is that?

Comment: S3 does only have objects with keys, folders do not exist. What looks like folders are just parts of the key separated by a `/`. The workaround is creating empty files in some paths to make folders "appear" to exist. But you should not need that.

Comment: @luk2302 You should but that as an answer.